# SharePoint Term Store as a Webpart Page Filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, term-store, connection-filters

I am trying to use a Term Store as a filter for multiple web parts on a single page similar to the way a document library can be filtered using the term store. In years past, I used to do similar on a web-part page using a site list instead of a term store and setting up connections to it and it worked perfectly but a little outdated now. I've spent several days researching it and have found nothing that does as I am hoping.

**As an example,**

1. Take a term set that contains: cat, dog, horse, mouse, cow
2. and a web-part page which contain lists, libraries, wiki, etc. web-parts where each entry contains one or more of the terms.
3. When I select "cat", all the web-parts, filter to display only the content from each element that contains "cat".
4. I don't want it to return a typical search results list.

Any idea if this is even possible with Term Sets?